# distroless dockerfile result in more than 1 images

Tags: docker, dockerfile, distroless

I just create a dockerfile for postgres using multi-step distroless image. I try to learn distroless because of security and size of the image. here's my dockerfile:

```
### First Stage ###
# Base Image
FROM postgres:13-alpine as build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/postgres

### Second Stage ###
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/postgres /usr/src/app/postgres
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/postgres

# Change user to non-root
USER 1002

# Run POSTGRES
CMD ["/postgres"]
```

After building the image the end result is 4 images instead of 1 like image below
[image]

I'm new to docker and as far as I know 1 dockerfile should result in 1 images, can anyone explain why this is happened?

Comment: Of course, it will be more than 1 image because you are using 2 images. You have used `Baseimage` of `postgres:13-alpine` and then you are copying the content from that image to another image called `gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10`.

Comment: Can you remove the screenshot and replace it with formatted text please? Images aren't searchable and it lowers the usefulness of your question. Also, I can't read text that small even when I'm zoomed in so people like me won't be able to offer much help.

Comment: Ok first of all, if we use base image and distroless by default it will pulled 2 images of base and distroless and when it combined it produce another image with name ezral (in my case). But what about the <none> one?

Comment: The image is a docker image list with 4 images name ezral, <none>, postgres, and gcr.io (distroless)